# Ruby on rails - get model's ID for selected radio button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my ruby on rails site, I show listings where I'd like to allow the user to add a listing to a wishlist. My listing model *has_many* wishlists, and my wishlist model *has_and_belongs_to_many* listings.

My *add_listing_to_a_wishlist.html.erb* file looks like:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <% @wishlists.each do |wishlist| %>
    <tr>
      <%= radio_button_tag("wishlist[id]", wishlist.id) %>
      <%= wishlist.name %>&nbsp;
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<%= link_to "Add listing to selected wishlist", wishlist_path %>
```

This successfully retrieves and shows each wishlist with a clickable radio button. I'd like to pass the selected wishlist (selected radio button) in to the link:

```
<%= link_to "Add listing to selected wishlist", wishlist_path %>
```

In my listings controller, I have a *add_listing_to_wishlist* function where I plan to use the id's of the respective listing and wishlist to add the listing. It looks like:

```
  def add_listing_to_wishlist
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
    @wishlists = Wishlist.find(params[:id])
    # [Logic for saving listing to wishlist here]
  end
```

How can I effectively pass the selected wishlist in from the UI to this function?

I am new to Ruby on Rails and frontend development so I am probably missing a simple concept; any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know maybe my way is no good, but it works for me. Just add form to your code.

```
<%= form_tag wishlist_path, method: :patch, remote: true do %>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <% @wishlists.each do |wishlist| %>
    <tr>
      <%= radio_button_tag("wishlist[id]", wishlist.id) %>
      <%= wishlist.name %>&nbsp;
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<%= submit_tag 'Add to wishlist', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep name as the param you want and change the value

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <% @wishlists.each do |wishlist| %>
    <tr>
      <%= radio_button_tag("wishlist", wishlist.id) %>
      <%= wishlist.name %>&nbsp;
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And in controller

```
 def add_listing_to_wishlist
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
    @wishlists = Wishlist.find(params[:wishlist])
    # [Logic for saving listing to wishlist here]
  end
```